# How to import a local module?

Tags: module, local, elm

I have a local auxiliary module, `List.Extensions`, which I would like to import into my Main.elm module. It exists in the same directory. When I try to do this, I get an error telling me that :

> I cannot find module 'List.Extensions'.
>
> Module 'Main' is trying to import it.

The content of `List.Extensions.elm` is:

```
module List.Extensions exposing (..)

test = 1
```

The content of `Main.elm` is:

```
import List.Extensions

[...]
```

I can't find any resources or guides to setting up local modules, how do I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like local elm modules have to be named according to the file system structure. So, `List.Extensions.elm` has to be **renamed** to `Extensions.elm` and **moved** to `List\Extensions.elm`. I could not find any documentation about this but anecdotally it seems to be the case. Posting in case someone else runs across the same problem.

Comment: This is correct. Here is a canonical documentation reference for this: http://www.elm-lang.org/docs/syntax#modules